# MVC3 with Oracle use ADO.NET would like a nice way of using IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net, ienumerable, oracle9i

I'm converting a web forms application to mvc3 , for the current database it is calling asmx web services returning datasets.  Since I'm rebuilding quite a bit of the application I really have no need or desire to be working with datasets.  Entity Framework is out of the question for the boss etc... Thus this is the existing type of Oracle code which returns 3 refcursors resulting in the dataset containing 3 datatables.  Here is the existing code:

```
    connection = new OracleConnection(EnvironmentSettings.connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            command = new OracleCommand("H16B.WEB_FACILITY.get_facility_queue", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            // Input Parameters
            command.Parameters.Add("pfacility", OracleDbType.Varchar2, facilityCode, ParameterDirection.Input);
            // Output Parameters
            command.Parameters.Add("pqueue", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            command.Parameters.Add("psubmitting", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            command.Parameters.Add("psubmitted", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
```

So What I would like to do is instead of using a dataset, use a collection  a List or IEnumerable .   Could anyone show me how to capture the data into the list (would I want 3 lists , the current webmethod output is a dataset.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Command.ExecuteNonQuery(), each of your ref cursor parameters should contain a Value that is either an OracleDataReader or an OracleRefCursor, depending on the internal settings of the parameter.

So, you should be able to start with something like this:

```
IDataReader queueReader = (IDataReader)command.Parameters["pqueue"].Value;
```

If it turns out to be an OracleRefCursor instead, you can use a GetDataReader on it for the same effect.

Since the contents are simple in this case, you may be able to just cast it to an IEnumerable directly; otherwise, you may need to fill a generic list or collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DefaulViews from the DataSet Tables, they implement IEnumberable.

About Dataview in the msdn docs: 
'Represents a databindable, customized view of a DataTable for sorting, filtering, searching, editing, and navigation.'

UPDATE: If you want to use collections directly as output take a look at [this site](http://unknownerror.net/2011-05/oracle-handbook-series-4-odp-net-and-complex-plsql-data-type-to-put-the-odp-asp-net-plsql-complex-data-types-that-6-27759) (horribly formatted though :/)

As you can see in the article, you will have to change something in your Oracle procedures as well. For example if you want to use plsql associative arrays, the output parameters cannot be refcursors, but have to be plsql tables.

Comment: I wish to skip the whole dataset thus 
   `DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);`

Instead I want to fill a collection list(s) instead.

Comment: I have used ADO for years and wish to skip using a datareader / datatable / dataset  and get my data from Oracle directly to a collection, does anyone know how to do this?  (Again, no Entity Framework thus no dbcontext / IQueryable .  All the mvc examples seem to use EF, but with Oracle EF in beta and does not even work with Oracle 9.2 ... I need to call Oracle stored procedures and put them into a Collection ... a List ... Dictionary  something lightweight.  Then IEnumerable I will use.   Thanks , Tom

Comment: I have used PLSQLAssociative Array's in the past as output parameters from Oracle.You mean something like that?  I can show example code if you want.

Comment: No, I cannot change the existing stored procs.  I am just wanting to grab the data in a lightweight dictionary. If I need to first put it in a datareader or datatable I can, I just was hoping for a way to skip those and get right to List  For example I can get a dataset right now and do this `List<IClient> clients = (from c in dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable() .......`  but i wish to skip putting the data into these datasets / datatables etc..   thanks